# Assembler Pin Change Interrupt in Atmega328p - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega

I am trying to do my first steps in programming a PCI in Assembler. It works in the simulator (AVR Studio), but it does not work when uploaded to my Arduino. The idea is to toggle a light when an interrupt is triggered. Please help me find out what is wrong.

```
.include "m328pdef.inc"

.def temp0 = R16
.def select = R17
.def temp1 = R18
.def flagint = R20

.org $0000
            jmp SETUP
.org $0012
            jmp PCI_ROT

SETUP:      ldi temp0, low(RAMEND)
            out SPL, temp0
            ldi temp0, high(RAMEND)
            out SPH, temp0      

            ldi temp0, $FF
            out DDRD, temp0     ; Arduino Pins 22 - 29 (PORTA), Data Bit 0 - 7
            out PORTD, temp0
            ldi temp0, $00
            out DDRB, temp0

            ldi temp0, $01      ; PCI 0 activated, Arduino Pin 21
            sts PCICR, temp0
            ldi temp0, $03      ; PCI pins activated
            sts PCMSK0, temp0
            sei

MAIN:       nop
            jmp MAIN

PCI_ROT:    in select, PINB
            ldi flagint, $01
            rcall SWITCH
            reti

SWITCH:     in temp0, PIND
            ldi temp1, $FF
            eor temp0, temp1
            out PORTD, temp0
            ret
```

Comment: If you could write it in C it would be much easier for others to help.  After you get the C code to working, you can get GCC to show you an assembly listing if you really want to be programming in assembly.  Also, how did you test it, and what were the expected results versus the actual results?

Answer (score 0):

I did get the PCI to work now, and the problem was a bouncey switch. I made a simple debounced switch with two resistors and a condensator. See here:
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/switch-bounce-how-to-deal-with-it/